# Retrieve image long raw datatype stored in oracle database in php

Tags: php, oracle, laravel

I tried to display image stored in oracle database 
I get it as decode data 
I tried to this code but not work

first way

```
  $img= studimage::select('studimage')->where('studnum',$id)->first();
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

   echo ($img->studimage) ;
```

sec-way

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'. base64_encode($img->studimage). '" />';
```

the two ways does not work :(

Comment: Yeah, I don't think *that* code will work. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: You have not showed us the code you have tried.

Comment: Can you please include that in your post ***and*** format it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using this same functionality in one of my project, please check my code below

you can either make a page that will render the image

```
<img src="image.php?id=123" />
```

That image.php page would have this:

```
$sql = "SELECT image FROM images WHERE image_id = " . (int) $_GET['id'];
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_execute($stid);
$row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
if (!$row) {
header('Status: 404 Not Found');
} else {
$img = $row['IMAGE']->load();
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
print $img;
}
```

Or, you could base64 encode it into the src (note, not all browsers handle this well):

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($img); ?>" />
```

Comment: here image data MM*�����J�:B(1�Oracle Multimedia Toolkit, 6.0o���

Comment: In database change column datatype to blob

Comment: I changed it into blob but have error Object of class OCI-Lob could not be converted to string

Comment: Truncate the table and then change the datatype after that store fresh image

Comment: same error :(  Object of class OCI-Lob could not be converted to string

Comment: can some body help me?

Comment: Check the LOB chapter of http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html